# Class of "distance-preserving functions" -- already known in math?

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

Let $(M_1,d_1)$ and $(M_2,d_2)$ be two metric spaces. I am wondering if the class of functions $f:M_1\to M_2$ that satisfy the following property is known in math (and if so -- what these class of functions is called):

$d_1( a_1,b_1 )=d_1( a_1',b_1' ) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ d_2( f(a_1),f(b_1) )=d_2( f(a_1'),f(b_1') )$

In words: If $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_1',b_1')$ have the same distances in $M_1$, then their images $(f(a_1),f(b_1))$ and $(f(a_1'),f(b_1'))$ must have the same distances in $M_2$.

In literature, I could find the concept of [Isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry), which seems to be close to the above but still different: Isometries compare distances over the spaces $M_1$ and $M_2$, while the class of functions above compares distances only in the individual spaces.

Comment: Besides, doesn't $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ satisfy the property despite not being one-to-one?

Comment: Good point - I'll delete and rethink

Comment: Another example: the natural map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I had been thinking of an isometry - duh.

Comment: One interesting thing to note is that these maps preserve equilateral triangles. A quick google search lead to [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225128757_On_mappings_preserving_equilateral_triangles). In short, if $M_1 = M_2 = E$ is some Euclidean space, then such functions are similarity transformations (isometry times a positive constant) when $\dim E \geq 3$. The same is true for $\dim E = 2$ if measurability is assumed. Other interesting observations can also be found there for Euclidean spaces.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this notion besides naming it? One class of such maps is called "snow-flaking", see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386514/when-is-a-metric-space-a-snowflake). More precisely, if $(X,d)$ is a metric space then for each $a\in (0,1)$, the metric $d^a$ on $X$ is called "a snow-flaking" of the metric $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is the same as asking for the map $f$ between two metric spaces to satisfy the following property: There exists some map $\eta: \mathbb{R_+} \to \mathbb{R_+}$ such that for all $x,y \in M_1$: $d_2(f(x),f(y)) = \eta(d_1(x,y))$.
If the map $\eta$ is additionally continuously monotonously increasing, then functions as $f$ are usually called *scale metric transfomations*. There are some examples in Deza-Deza, Encyclopedia of Distances (Chapter 4).